# isMouseOver in Canvas with Path

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry for my English.
I'm new in WPF and I have one question.
I want to change the visual style of a `Canvas` with included Path (image) when `isMouseOver` is triggered.

Steps:

- Put Canvas to Window
- Include Path

Result:

```
<Canvas x:Name="mycanvas" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
         <Path Width="40" Height="30" Canvas.Left="18" Canvas.Top="23" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 18,23L 58,23L 58,53L 18,53L 18,23 Z M 54,31L 22,31L 22,49L 54,49L 54,31 Z M 45,38L 45,42L 31,42L 31,38L 45,38 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
```

Then I combined the canvas with `Button` style and Fill "Path" with White color if `isMouseOver` occurs.

My style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Canvas x:Name="mycanvas" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path x:Name="path" Width="40" Canvas.Top="23" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Left="18" Height="30" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 18,23L 58,23L 58,53L 18,53L 18,23 Z M 54,31L 22,31L 22,49L 54,49L 54,31 Z M 45,38L 45,42L 31,42L 31,38L 45,38 Z "/>
        </Canvas>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="mycanvas">
        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="path" Value="White"/>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But `IsMouseOver` works only when the mouse passes through the image ("Path") surface.
But the image surface is small and contain breaks.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `Canvas` *`Background`* put a `SolidColorBrush` with a *`Transparent`* color:

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Canvas x:Name="mycanvas" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
                        <Canvas.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                        </Canvas.Background>
                        <Path x:Name="path" Width="40" Canvas.Top="23" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Left="18" Height="30" Fill="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 18,23L 58,23L 58,53L 18,53L 18,23 Z M 54,31L 22,31L 22,49L 54,49L 54,31 Z M 45,38L 45,42L 31,42L 31,38L 45,38 Z "/>
                    </Canvas>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" SourceName="mycanvas">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="path" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```